# Biztalk file is not showing up and cannot be sent

Tags: biztalk

I have set up a BizTalk environment and am trying to follow a tutorial on github: [wmmihaa / BizTalk-Server---Developing-Integration-Solutions](https://github.com/wmmihaa/BizTalk-Server---Developing-Integration-Solutions).

Unfortunately when I have configured the server as the steps say and then when I copy the path that the tutorial says I should copy into send ports it does not show up in file explorer. Then I create the path myself and browse for it (same name as in tutorial) and I proceed to start the created application the text file does not show up in the folder and cannot be copied to the receive location as the tutorial says I should.

I have tried restarting the computer and application and tried to change the path (don't know if I can). Does anyone know why the file might not be showing up?

[image: Image of path below]

Comment: Is the file picked up from the receive location?  Can you se a suspended message in BizTalk Admin console?

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create the folder manually, just setting the path in the send port won't create it.

There can be various issues

1. The file is not even picked up.  This can be due to

a. The Reive location not enabled.  Fix: Enable the receive location.
b. The file mask on the receive location doesn't match the file.  Fix: Either change the filename or the filemask.
c. The BizTalk Host Instance user doesn't have the correct permission on the folder to pick the file up. Fix: Give the BizTalk user Full permissions of the folder
d. The host instance that the receive location is running under is Stopped. Fix: Star the host instance.

2. The file is picked up but the message suspended.  This is caused by the filter/subscription on the send port not matching the Promoted Properties on in the message context.  Fix: Fix the send port Filter.
3. The message is in an active state but not sending.  Cause: The host instance that the send port is under is not started.  Fix:  Start the Host Instance the Send Port runs under.